# Apple iWork Pages: How can I add a Section Break on the same page

Tags: pages, iwork

I'm writing a user's guide with iWork Pages. The document has multiple sections and sometime on a single page, I'll have an end of a section and a start of another section.

I cannot figure out how to add Section Break on the same page. Normally, the newer section would override the previous section on the same page, but in Pages, adding a Section Break in the middle of the page will throw you to a new page (Section Break + Pages Break). I want to remain both section on the same page.

I need to Section Break for footer and table of content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that while a Layout Break has the option to start a new page or not start a new page,
[image]

a Section Break always starts a new page. Thus, the header at the top of the page is always from the same section as the footer at the bottom of the page.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and found the answer at http://support.apple.com/kb/PH15334. You just have to select the section you want to change. In my case I wanted to have two columns on part of the page. I selected that section, then went to the inspector and selected two columns in the text section.